# Get a specific line from a url using php

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

Hi I want get a specific line from a given url... such as From [this](http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=ae2f63619e8d4cc4bd0beaf9fd73839e) url, I would like to get the line "GBP": 0.632956. I think I have to use preg functions but can any one please provide me an example how to get it..

Thanks.

Comment: Show us some code that you've tried.

Comment: You should be parsing the `json` with `json_decode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a JSON response, so you don't need any regular expressions:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=ae2f63619e8d4cc4bd0beaf9fd73839e');
$data = json_decode($response);
echo $data->rates->GBP;
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/v17F11)

See also: [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/json_decode)

Comment: Oh my goodness... Thanks a lot... It just worked... Can I ask you another question? How can I use the output in somewhere else without displaying? Thanks again..

Comment: @user1946440 just assign it to a variable instead.

Comment: Thanks.. as I can see the output is 0.632956 . How can I just take the first two digit after "." .  I mean I want the output like 0.63. Even if there is now fractions then I want to get a default .00 such as if GBP is 48 then I want the output like 48.00